# Setting cachePolicy of a parse query crashes application

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm developing in Swift using the latest version of Parse from the website. I am attempting to set my cache policy to the NetworkElseCache value, which is displayed below:

```
let userRelation = User.currentUser()?.relationForKey("friends")
let userQuery = userRelation!.query()
userQuery.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
userQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (users, error) -> Void in
    print("Success")
}
```

The error occurs on the line:

```
userQuery.cachePolicy = .NetworkElseCache
```

and if the line is removed, the application runs fine, the error produced is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Method not allowed when Pinning is enabled.'
```

I really don't have any idea what to do from here, I only started iOS development about a week ago using Parse and Swift, so I'm a bit on the lost side. I don't understand the callstack either, or how it will help me find my problem.

Comment: Are you using Parse with Core Data?

Comment: @pbush25 I may be, I'm not sure? I'm using (a)NSManaged variables, as that's what I was taught, is this what you mean?

Comment: In your app delegate when you initialize Parse do you call `Parse.enableLocalDatastore`?

Comment: @pbush25 - Yes, I do. It's my understanding that this is a caching tool, which will be useful considering my application contains many pictures and real-time messaging.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the LocalDataStore in your AppDelegate.m

So comment following line

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore()          // Comment this line and try
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [full explanation](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/7) from the engineers at Parse. But yes, long story short, if you're using local datastore, you will not be able to also use different cache policies.